# I don't understand why using throw keyword

Tags: php, swiftmailer

```
 throw PHPUnit_Util_InvalidArgumentHelper::factory(1, 'string');
```

why the coder used throw in this line?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be used?

Comment: Because they wanted to throw an exception? Why not ask them or provide a lot more context

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurred in your script, it's thrown using the throw keyword.
Example:

```
if(some_condition) {
    throw new Exception("Value must be 1 or below");
}
```

The code above will get an error like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'
with message 'Value must be 1 or below' in C:\webfolder\test.php:6
```

Read this article for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp